# a second order ordinary differential equation to be solved by method of variation of parameters

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

how to solve $$x^2y"-2x(1-x)y'+2(x+1)y=x^3$$ by method of variation of parameters.
how do you find solution of the above equation?
iam familiar with method of variation of parameters but dont know how to find $y_1$ and $y_2.$ please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For to find $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ you need to solve the homogeneous-equation: $x^{2}y''-2x(1-x)y'+2(x+1)y=0$ for to solve this I think you can read  here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sturm-LiouvilleEquation.html since that we can re-write the homogeneous equation a: $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{2x}y'}{x^{2}}\right)+\frac{2e^{2x}(1+x)y}{x^{4}}=0$.

Comment: Note that a solution for the homogeneous equation is: $y_{1}=e^{-2x}(x-1)x^{2}$ and you can find the other solution using the Abel's formula: http://fac-staff.seattleu.edu/oliveras/web/teaching/DiffEq/Notes/SO_Lecture_3.pdf

Comment: Are you familiar with how to deal with equations with variable coefficients? Do you know the method of Frobenius?

Comment: anyone please solve this.

Comment: i dont know how to solve ode with variable coefficients

Answer (score 0):

You might first need to set an interval for $x$, as the equation degenerates as $x\rightarrow 0$.